# Как удалить строки в excel

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как удалить строки в столбце A которые не содержат гиперссылки

Comment: эксель это не программирование, это просто таблицы, зачем на SO спрашиваешь?

Comment: @MrArsikk, строки можно удалить не только силами самого Excel, но и с помощью VBA

Answer (score 0):

1. Выделяешь все на листе (Ctrl + A)
2. Разъединяешь объединенные ячейки (Объединить и поместить в центре жмешь)
3. Ориентируемся по колонке E. Пишем условие для столбца F. Если E > 0;1;0.
4. Ставим фильтр на колонке F
5. Выбираем фильтром только строки с F = 1
6. Можно скопировать результат и перенести на новый лист.

Успехов!

Comment: можешь пожалуйста помощь не могу разобраться, можно как нибудь выйти с тобой на связь?